# Which champions have abilities with reduced cooldown on 'failure'?

Tags: league-of-legends

In League of Legends, when **Caitlyn**'s ultimate, *Ace in the Hole*, "fails" - that is, the enemy champion you're targeting dies before you charge up - the cooldown is only *4* seconds, instead of the full *90*.

Are there any other champions with skills that act like this?

Comment: The Summoner Spell 'Teleport' acts like this, if your teleport gets cancelled (tower you are teleporting to dies, you get stunned while trying to teleport) then you only get a half cooldown.

Comment: VI also has that, when her "Q" gets interrupted

Answer (score 4):

**Pantheon**'s ultimate's cooldown is reduced to 10 seconds, if interrupted or cancelled.

**Zed**'s ultimate's cooldown is reduced to 4-5 seconds, if the target dies before Zed arrives to the target.

**Vi**'s Q's cooldown is reduced to 3 seconds, if interrupted.